# UIImage in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimage

I'm trying to put image in UITableViewCell. I use [SSMessages](https://github.com/markrickert/ssmessagesviewcontroller) style for my messages.
[image]

Tried something like `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:message.messageText];` but it isn't work. Any suggestions? Maybe need my other code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SSMessageTableViewCellBubbleView's leftBackgroundImage and add it this way to your table view

```
SSMessageTableViewCellBubbleView *imageBubbleView = [SSMessageTableViewCellBubbleView alloc]     init];
imageBubbleView. leftBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:message.messageText];

[cell.contentView addSubview:imageBubbleView];
```

I expect this to work!

Answer (score 1):

First set the background color of the image view for troubleshooting:

```
cell.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255.0f/255.0f) green:(0.0f/255.0f) blue:(0.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
```

Set the image:

```
cell.imageView.image = ...;
```

Set the image view frame:

```
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, cell.imageView.image.size.width, cell.imageView.image.size.height);
```

Add the image view as a subview of the cell.

Bring this subview to the front:

```
[cell bringSubviewToFront:[cell.imageView superview]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to call `[cell setNeedsLayout]` or `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` in order to get the cell to update the frame of the `UIImageView` for the new image.  Simply setting image on the `UIImageView` will do nothing if the frame of the `UIImageView` is `CGRectZero`.

To see if the frame is zero, try adding a background color or a layer border using:

```
cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```